# Is there a way to show a normalized version of a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

There are plenty of parametrized type aliases that are used in typescript and it can sometimes be difficult to determine what the actual type is below all the abstraction layers. Is there some way to normalize a concrete type remove all type aliases from it?

For example, if I have these types:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null
type Num = number
type Base = {
  a: Num
  b: boolean
  c: Maybe<{ x: Num }>
}

type Hello = Pick<Base, 'a' | 'c'>
```

I want some way to show that `Hello` is the same as:

```
type Hello = {
  a: number
  c: { x: number } | null
}
```

I am also interested in if there is a way to do shallow normalization and convert `Pick<Base, 'a' | 'c'>` into

```
type Hello = {
  a: Num
  c: Maybe<{ x: Num}>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since typescript uses structural typing `Pick<Base, 'a' | 'c'>` and the expanded out version are essentially the same type written in a different way, so I would not try to expand out the type for any reasons of compatibility.

If you only want to expand type to inspect it, there is a trick to do it. You can use a mapped typed in an intersection with `{}`. This will make the compiler expand out the type.

**This behavior is not documented or guaranteed to work in the future.** So you can use it, but don't depend on it in any meaningful way.

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null
type Num = number
type Base = {
  a: Num
  b: boolean
  c: Maybe<{ x: Num }>
}

type Hello = Pick<Base, 'a' | 'c'>


type Id<T> = {} & {
  [P in keyof T]: Id<T[P]>
}

type HelloExpand = Id<Hello>
// On hover you can see in the tooltip (pro tip, if you are quick you can copy a tooltip in VSCode and the playground):
// type HelloExpand = {
//     a: number;
//     c: {
//         x: number;
//     } | null;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IFgAoUSKAOVIFscTXkAnW+6AITgBnaLgDetKFDgAuJq0lREcxAHtV5CHGKKAxnPhJUYqAA85zNgF8MtK7V7hoACQiVV7AAoBLXQGsUQREAGigAcjgwwnDdMNsaBzonKABJABN0LHErKAAyKAkaKQBtTyhvYig-CBBVADM8AF05dPRSxvj7BKSGV3cAUVMwbTT2Vr7yVXiAemmoAHlKgAtVADcILiha0ihdbSgRaAqoYCXoYHVyYG8wGVpZk+SJ1UHh4lHxe7mpKVkOFm4AG4vj8pPoCiDQaDzP8gZCfjkiGRKMCaA8rEA)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. And yes, I am very well aware of the structural typing and thought I made that clear in the question.